# Why is camel kafka producer very slow?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-producer-api

I am using apache camel kafka as client for producing message, what I observed is kafka producer taking 1 ms to push a message, if I merge message into batch by using camel aggregation then it is taking 100ms to push a single message.

Brief description of installation
3 kafka clusther 16Core 32GB RAM

Sample Code

```
    String endpoint="kafka:test?topic=test&brokers=nodekfa:9092,nodekfb:9092,nodekfc:9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536";      
    Message message = new Message();
    String payload = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(message);
    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.watch();
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        producerTemplate.sendBody(endpoint,ExchangePattern.InOnly, payload);
    }
    logger.info("Time taken to push {} message is {}",size,stopWatch.getElasedTime());
```

camel producer endpoint

```
kafka:[topic]?topic=[topic]&brokers=[brokers]&maxInFlightRequest=1
```

I am getting throughput of 1000/s though kafka documentation brag producer tps around 100,000.

Let me know if there is any bug in camel-kafka or in kafka itself.

Producer config

```
     acks = 1
        batch.size = 65536
        bootstrap.servers = [nodekfa:9092, nodekfb:9092, nodekfc:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.id = 
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 305000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class  org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Test Logs

```
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,781]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 3 millis for the exchange on the route : null
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,781]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 3 millis to send to external system : kafka://test?brokers=nodekfa%3A9092%2Cnodekfb%3A9092%2Cnodekfc%3A9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536&topic=test by thead http-nio-8551-exec-6
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,783]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 2 millis for the exchange on the route : null
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,783]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 2 millis to send to external system : kafka://test?brokers=nodekfa%3A9092%2Cnodekfb%3A9092%2Cnodekfc%3A9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536&topic=test by thead http-nio-8551-exec-6
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,784]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 1 millis for the exchange on the route : null
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,785]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 2 millis to send to external system : kafka://test?brokers=nodekfa%3A9092%2Cnodekfb%3A9092%2Cnodekfc%3A9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536&topic=test by thead http-nio-8551-exec-6
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,786]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 1 millis for the exchange on the route : null
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,786]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 1 millis to send to external system : kafka://test?brokers=nodekfa%3A9092%2Cnodekfb%3A9092%2Cnodekfc%3A9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536&topic=test by thead http-nio-8551-exec-6
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,788]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 2 millis for the exchange on the route : null
DEBUG [2019-06-02 17:30:46,788]  c.g.p.f.u.AuditEventNotifier: >>> Took 2 millis to send to external system : kafka://test?brokers=nodekfa%3A9092%2Cnodekfb%3A9092%2Cnodekfc%3A9092&lingerMs=0&maxInFlightRequest=1&producerBatchSize=65536&topic=test by thead http-nio-8551-exec-6
INFO  [2019-06-02 17:30:46,788]  c.g.p.f.a.MessageApiController: Time taken to push 5 message is 10ms
```

It is clearly taking minimum 1ms for message, default worker pool max size is 20 , if i set compression codec to snappy this will make performance worst.

Let me know what I am missing !!

Comment: I'd suggest increasing or removing `maxInFlightRequest=1`

Comment: No change after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing the same issue, from this email https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Kafka-Producer-Performance-tp5785767p5785860.html I used https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/aggregate-eip.html to create batches and got better performance

```java
from("direct:dp.events")
.aggregate(constant(true), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(3)
.to(kafkaUri)
.to("log:out?groupInterval=1000&groupDelay=500")
.end();
```

I get :

```
 INFO  Received: 1670 new messages, with total 13949 so far. Last group took: 998 millis which is: 1,673.347 messages per second. average: 1,262.696
```

This is using 1 Azure Event Hub using Kafka Protocol w/ one partition. The weird thing is that when I use another EH w/ 5 partitions I get bad performance compare to the 1 partition example...

### Multiple partitions (UPDATE)

I was able to get 3K message per second by increasing the workerPoolCoreSize and the workerPoolMaxSize, in addition to adding partition keys to the messages and adding aggregation before sending to kafka endpoint